# How to switch to application using first letter of their name like the RCMD tool on mac?

Tags: shortcut-keys, shortcuts, workflow

There is this Mac app called RCMD which you switch your apps using the left cmd and first letter of the application, like for example if you want to switch to Chrome you do "RCMD + C", I was thinking of doing the same thing on Ubuntu, any workarounds or tools to achieve this kind of workflow?
Thank you everyone.